# How to create further chunks of javascript if it exceeds certain file size limit?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there any way that I can automate further chunking of javascript file if it exceeds from a defined file size limit.

To explain the problem further. 
Lets just say I have different modules "product landing page(plp)" & "product detail page(pdp)". Both has different JS files already ("plp.js`60kb`" and "pdp.js`55kb`" accordingly).

*** How can the files be chunkified further if it exceed from certain file size limit? ***

So the expected output when the limit is set as `50kb` should be...

```
plp-1.js `50kb`
plp-2.js `10kb~`

pdp-1.js `50kb`
pdp-2.js` `5kb~`
```

Comment: What limit are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I am referring to file size limit

Comment: Is this a limit you would like to set?

Comment: Yes and should be configurable, so that I can alter it later if needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the real goal here?

Comment: Ok so once that is done I can apply the same mechanism to bind the page accordingly and serve the asset on http2 to improve the page performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify entry points in you `webpack.config.js` file:

```
entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    another: './src/another-module.js',
  },
```

It will create a new chunk output:

```
            Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
another.bundle.js  550 KiB  another  [emitted]  another
  index.bundle.js  550 KiB    index  [emitted]  index
Entrypoint index = index.bundle.js
Entrypoint another = another.bundle.js
```

See docs here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Laszlo
Actually my problem is that I need another.bundle.js to be chunkified further if it exceed from a certain limit. If say the limit defined is 200kb the another.bundle.js should be in three files (another.bundle-1.js + another.bundle-2.js + another.bundle-3.js) because its 550Kib (200Kib + 200Kib + 150~Kib). Hope I am clear now.